# Removing multiple occurence of names of attributes while zooming in

Tags: labeling, mapserver, sld, filter, text

I was writing an SLD so that it works with MapServer. The problem I encountered is that there are multiple occurrences of names of attributes while zooming in. Is there a way to correct this?

Below is the SLD I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>        
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>waterarea18</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>140000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>360000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>forest</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#4adb86</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>20000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>140000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>forest</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#4adb86</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>name</Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">3</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>1000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>20000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>forest</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#4adb86</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>name</Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">8</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>140000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>360000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>water</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#85cbf7</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>20000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>140000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>water</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#85cbf7</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>name</Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">3</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>1000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>20000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>water</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#85cbf7</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>name</Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">8</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>140000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>360000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>park</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#8eff84</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>20000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>140000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>park</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#8eff84</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>name</Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">3</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>1000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>20000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <Filter>
                        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <PropertyName>type</PropertyName>
                            <Literal>park</Literal>
                        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#8eff84</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>name</Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">8</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: is your map tiled?

Comment: Your SLD is invalid.  `Filter` is incorrect after `MaxScaleDenominator` . it should appear just after the `Rule` as `<ogc:Filter> <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>forest</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Filter>`